# Connect member function from unknown class to boost signal

Tags: c++, boost, signals, pointer-to-member

I am aware that there is quite a few topics around this, but I just can't figure it out.

I am working for a Signal driven input manager for my game and since I need to control multiple players, I need to connect a member function of a PlayerController instance to my vector of signals.

Problem is, that there is not only going to be a PlayerController, but also a MenuController etc. So I will need to connect a member function of a MenuController to the signal aswell.

I am pretty sure I am close to the solution, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Can someone help me with the registerEvent function signature and how to call the connect method.

InputManager.tcc

```
#include "boost/function.hpp"
template<class T>
void InputManager::registerEvent(SDL_Keycode key,KeyState state,boost::function<void ()> const& function)
{
    auto &inputEvents = (state == KeyState::Up) ? m_keyUpEvents : m_keyDownEvents;

    if(inputEvents.find(key) == inputEvents.end())
    {
        inputEvents.insert(std::make_pair(key, boost::signals2::signal<void()>()));
        m_keyStates[key] = KeyState::Up;
    }

    inputEvents[key].connect(boost::bind(T::function, instance));
}
```

InputManager.hpp:

```
#ifndef SSB_INPUTMANAGER_HPP
#define SSB_INPUTMANAGER_HPP

#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <SDL_keycode.h>
#include <SDL_events.h>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

enum KeyState{
    Down,
    Up
};

class InputManager
{
public:
    InputManager();
    template<class T>
    void registerEvent(SDL_Keycode key,KeyState state, boost::function<void ()> const& function);
void pollEvent(SDL_Event event);

private:
    std::map<SDL_Keycode, boost::signals2::signal<void ()>> m_keyDownEvents;
    std::map<SDL_Keycode, boost::signals2::signal<void ()>> m_keyUpEvents;
    std::map<SDL_Keycode, KeyState> m_keyStates;
};

#include "InputManager.tcc"

#endif //SSB_INPUTMANAGER_HPP
```

PlayerController.hpp

```
#ifndef SSB_PLAYERCONTROLLER_HPP
#define SSB_PLAYERCONTROLLER_HPP

class PlayerController
{
public:
    void jump();
private:
    Player m_player;
};

#endif //SSB_PLAYERCONTROLLER_HPP
```

Then I want to call in an initialization method somewhere in my game:

```
PlayerController playerController;
InputManager inputController;

inputController.registerEvent(SDLK_0, KeyState::Down, playerController.jump());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `boost::function<>` and `std::function<>` already do *type erasure*. This means that they "abstract" away any bound parameters.

The `this*` argument is really *just* that: a parameter. So, the same goes for it.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru (c++11)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/809da3345d40a449)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

enum SDL_Keycode { K_A, K_B, K_C, K_Up, K_Down, K_Right, K_Left, K_LCtrl, /*etc....*/ };
enum KeyState { Down, Up };

struct InputManager {
  void registerEvent(SDL_Keycode key, KeyState state, boost::function<void()> const &function) {
      auto& map = state == Up? m_keyUpEvents : m_keyDownEvents;
      map[key].connect(function);
  }

  void poll_event() {
      // hardcoded for demo
      m_keyDownEvents[K_B]();
  }

private:
  std::map<SDL_Keycode, boost::signals2::signal<void()>> m_keyDownEvents;
  std::map<SDL_Keycode, boost::signals2::signal<void()>> m_keyUpEvents;
  std::map<SDL_Keycode, KeyState> m_keyStates;
};

struct Player {};

class PlayerController {
public:
  void jump() {
      std::cout << "Player jumped\n";
  }

private:
  Player m_player;
};

class CowController {
public:
  void moo() {
      std::cout << "Cow mooed\n";
  }
};

int main() {
    InputManager inputController;
    PlayerController p;

    inputController.poll_event(); // nothing

    inputController.registerEvent(K_B, Down, [&] { p.jump(); });

    inputController.poll_event(); // player jumps

    CowController c;
    inputController.registerEvent(K_B, Down, [&] { c.moo(); });

    inputController.poll_event(); // player jumps, cow moos
}
```

Prints

```
Player jumped
Player jumped
Cow mooed
```

### C++03

If you don't have lambdas, you can use Boost Bind (or `std::tr1::bind`):

```
inputController.registerEvent(K_B, Down, boost::bind(&PlayerController::jump, boost::ref(p)));

inputController.poll_event(); // player jumps

CowController c;
inputController.registerEvent(K_B, Down, boost::bind(&CowController::moo, boost::ref(c)));
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f755d7d54b61b9d)</kbd>**

Comment: This is awesome, was struggling a lot trying to get this to work! Thank you!